# Most optimal method of implementing tappable shapes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, core-graphics

I'm building an app that provides an editable canvas similarly to photoshop or illustrator (currently using `SpriteKit`). I'm encountering some performance issues when displaying a large number of nodes (1000+) as you might imagine.

Currently, I've got an `SKScene` with `SKShapeNodes` on it. They presently do not have any images and are simply filled with a color. Their shape paths (`CGPath`s) vary from circles, to bezier paths. Each shape currently has an `SKPhysicsBody` with the same path as the rendered shape that is used to detect taps.

The performance issues can be described by:

- slowness when adding 1000 nodes (circles), uses about 0.1mb of memory per node
- slowness when moving 1000 nodes (circles)
- slowness when generating a texture from 1000 nodes (circles)

Disabling PhysicsBodies **doesn't** substantially improve performance, but does improve CPU load (jumps from constant 60% to 1% or so)

Most users will not be working with 1000 nodes, but I'd like to implement the optimal solution.

What I'd like is two have two layers:

- A **render** layer on which I'd like to be able to render `CGPath`s with strokes and fills (preferably choosing the stroke end cap style among other little things)
- An **interaction** layer on which I'd like to be able to detect taps inside `CGPath`s and stroke CGPath's with a color to indicate highlighting.

How can I accomplish this or a similar solution that will improve the speed at which I can render 1000 circles?

Comment: "I'm building something like photoshop or illustrator using SpriteKit"  Huh!?

Comment: @ElTomato it's not as crazy as it sounds! SpriteKit as a lot of nice tools for emulating editable canvas behavior. Obviously it has limitations, as I am describing.

Comment: I don't have a problem with that.  I thought you wanted to say that you are building a game with Photoshop and Illustrator.  Peace.

Comment: hey there, please upvote my answer that you accepted if you don't mind :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use SKShapeNode, it needs 1 draw call per shapenode. You can create a shape, then "cast" it to a SpriteNode before adding it to the scene:

```
func shapeToSprite(_ shape: SKShapeNode) -> SKSpriteNode {
  let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKView().texture(from: shape))
  sprite.physicsBody = shape.physicsBody // Or create a new PB from alpha mask (may be slower, IDK)
  shape.physicsBody = nil
  return sprite
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
  let shape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 60)
  addChild(shapeToSprite(shape))
}
```

This would suck though if you needed to constantly edit the size / shape of your shape in a way that isn't doable via scaling or SKWarpGeometry

To detect taps like this, you just need to either 1, Set a name for the SpriteNode then look for it in touchesBegan, or 2, subclass a SpriteNode and override it's touchesBegan.

Also, if you need to just have a static image, you can bit-blit thousands of nodes onto 1 texture.
[Sprite Kit: A Lot of sprites (1000+) with Bit Blitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011694/sprite-kit-a-lot-of-sprites-1000-with-bit-blitting)

http://www.sdkboy.com/2014/01/spritekit-bit-blitting-by-drawing-to-a-texture-for-performance-optimization/

So if you don't need every node to be touchable at all times, you can alternate between having physicsBodys and not, or switch layers from bitblitted to active.